# Convert to gray 1-bit, alpha 8-bit with ImageMagick

Tags: android, imagemagick

I am trying to convert Android app resources (icons and backgrounds) to the same format material icons are (in order save space and tint them):

[image]

```
$ identify -verbose ic_alarm_black_48dp.png 
Image: ic_alarm_black_48dp.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 192x192+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
```

This image has 8-bit depth and 1-bit gray channel depth.

Here is a test image I wanted to convert to format above (a shape with shadow on a transparent background):

[image: icon to be converted]

```
$ identify -verbose a.png 
Image: a.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
```

**I expect to get a 1-bit grayscale image with 8-bit alpha channel.**

I feel that I need to convert a source image to a 1-bit grayscale image (with all non-transparent pixels set to 1) and apply an extracted alpha mask on top.

Convert to 1-bit grayscale

```
`convert a.png -alpha extract -threshold 0 -negate -transparent white a-trans.png`
```

Apply mask on top

```
`convert a-trans.png \( a.png -alpha extract \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite a-result.png`
```

[image: expected result]

```
$ identify -verbose a-result.png 
Image: a-result.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
```

Last image is what I wanted to achieve. Could that conversion be optimized?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do? Do you want to convert the purple disk to be black and white? Or to have 8-bit alpha? Or to have 1-bit colour? You will lose the colour if you make it grey! What does the answer look like?

Comment: The answer is the first (alarm) and the last (black ellipse) image. As I stated, I expect to get a 1-bit grayscale image with 8-bit alpha channel. I do not need color, because the image will be tinted afterwards. Alpha channel is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
convert input.png -channel RGB -fill black -colorize 100%  result.png
```

[image]

```
Image: result.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Grayscale
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
```