# Convert anti-aliased grayscale to black/white + alpha

Tags: imagemagick

I have a scanned image of my signature that I’d like to use electronically.  The image is an anti-aliased black-and-white scan, looking something like this:

> [image: 1]

My desired output would be pure black-and-white, something that looks like this:

> [image: 2]

(*e.g.*, like the result of `convert sig.png -threshold 99% sig_bw.png`)
with the alpha channel re-creating the grayscale of the original scan.

(There are other ways I can add transparency so the image can be used as a stamp atop other images, but I want to enable a future step of changing the color of the “ink”.)

How can I accomplish this in ImageMagick?

I figured out how to use `convert sig.png -negate -alpha copy sig_mask.png` to create an image mask, but I can’t puzzle out how to combine this with sig_bw.png.

Comment: _[Convert to gray 1-bit, alpha 8-bit with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38307757/95580)_ asks something similar, but the answer gives me a completely black image, not what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you want in Imagemagick? Download the result to see the transparency.

Input:

[image]

```
convert line.png -alpha copy -channel a -negate +channel -alpha off -negate -threshold 0 -negate -alpha on newline.png
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you; but could you please also break this up into explicit steps so I can make sense of what you’re doing? I’m guessing it’s one line combining the flattened image (sig_bw.png) and the mask (sig_mask.png) that I’ve created in the question.

Comment: And yes, this is exactly the result I’m looking for, as confirmed by `convert newline.png -alpha off bwline.png`. But I’m hoping to understand the result also, not just achieve my goal.

Comment: See my explanation that I just added to the answer. Does that help?